# Error handling in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I am currently build a set of directives that we will be shipping to customer to use.

Now some of the directives has got required parameter and also some validation on parameters.

Is there some sort of guideline to what a person must do  if a required field is not there or a validation failed.

Must you default values,throw exception, or use angularjs exception handling thing.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are the one who has written a directive, you must be the one who should answer these questions...

`guideline to what a person must do if a required field is not there or a validation failed.`

only thing you can help with is making sure that if some required parameters are missing, is give some indication user of the directive, either by some exception logging or console messages etc.

its exactly like how angular tells us how to use ng-change or ng-click for that matter.

Comment: hi. Im more talking about the developer using the directive and not the end user. So at design time not runtime.

Comment: thats why i had writted, its how angularjs does to communicate how to use ng-click/ng-change with developers